# Invalid image data error: how to display image in Flutter app using aws s3 url?

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3

I'm using this code to display image:

```
Container(
        child: Image(
            image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                "https://zyle.s3.amazonaws.com/IMG_1_v%2BjwOGN%2BK6FmX2wA.png")),
      );
```

But it's showing the error:
[image]

Comment: this file is not a `png` file - it starts in hex with: `fd 4b 1e ae cf ec 6a bb` which is not a signature of any image file supported by flutter, also see [List of file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)

Comment: @pskink thanks I release that image is not uploading to aws with correct data. Solved now.

Comment: @sarru1291 how did you solved that uploading issue? I am struggling with the same problem now.

Comment: @VNikoyan I don't remember correctly, but it was an issue with file naming and this also does provide a way to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
Image.network("https://zyle.s3.amazonaws.com/IMG_1_v%2BjwOGN%2BK6FmX2wA.png")
```